# for following c code i getting error for loop : expected expression before ')' token

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

below C program run in online complier if it is helpful for solving error message
Thanks for answering question in advance!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    int arr[10],i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the size of array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  
for(i=0,i<n,i++){
   printf("Enter the elements in array:");
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);  
}
for(j=0,j<n,j++){
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);
}
return 0 ;
}
```

I want to create an array of n size(n is input from the user) and store elements in the array and display array, but I am getting an error message in for loop:  expected expression before ')' token                         because of that I cannot move further.

Comment: A typo. Replace```,``` with ```;``` in the for loop.

Comment: Aside: ```scanf``` returns some value, check it.

Comment: Note: You access out of bounds memory if ```n``` is more than ```10```, which is illegal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    int arr[10],i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the size of array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  
for(i=0,i<n,i++){
   printf("Enter the elements in array:");
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);  
}
for(j=0,j<n,j++){
    printf("%d\t",a[i]);
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This code has syntax errors in the for loops. (Same as in the OP.) In fact, your code is completely identical to the OP. So I don't see what this answer means, or why it was accepted.